# Failing to install new software

Tags: fedora

Im using Fedora 27 now. Today I tried to install openvpn by running

```
dnf install openvpn easy-rsa
```

This gives the following output:

```
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'pgdg95', disabling.
Last metadata expiration check: 1:33:10 ago on Tue 29 May 2018 01:37:39 PM IST.
Package openvpn-2.4.6-1.fc27.i686 is already installed, skipping.
Package easy-rsa-3.0.3-1.fc27.noarch is already installed, skipping.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

When I run these commands

```
dnf install network-manager-openvpn openvpn
dnf install vlc
dnf install kdevelop
```

These return the following output:

```
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'pgdg95', disabling.
Last metadata expiration check: 1:33:10 ago on Tue 29 May 2018 01:37:39 PM IST.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

I cant install new software packages in the terminal. Some amount of respite comes from dnfdragora dialog when it updates packages.

PS: I tried dnf clean all but in vain. 
I dont have vlc and kdevelop installed.

Comment: In your first example, it seems that `openvpn` and `easy-rsa` are already installed. Are they? Unfortunately I don't use Fedora, so I can't comment further on the `pgdg95` repo issue.

Comment: »»Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'pgdg95'«« : Well, then disable the pgdg95.repo .

Answer (score -1):

Try: `sudo dnf clean all && sudo dnf upgrade`